# Cocoa Convert NSArray/NSString of octals to NSData?

Tags: cocoa, nsarray, nsdata, des

I'm trying to covert this bit of C code to Cocoa and I'm struggling to figure out how.

```
  char *deskey = "123 456 789 101 112 131 415 161";
  unsigned char key[16];
  memset(key, 0, sizeof(key));
  sscanf(deskey, "%o %o %o %o %o %o %o %o",
    (int*)&key[0], (int*)&key[1], (int*)&key[2],
    (int*)&key[3], (int*)&key[4], (int*)&key[5],
    (int*)&key[6], (int*)&key[7]);
```

I've tried using NSMutableArray and NSData but having no luck.  I was able to scan the string and pull out the numbers, but I'm not sure how to store into NSData after that.

```
  NSMutableArray *enckey = [[[NSMutableArray alloc] init] autorelease];
  NSScanner *scanner = [NSScanner scannerWithString:self.deskey];
  int pos = 0;

  while ([scanner isAtEnd] == NO) {
    if ([scanner scanInt:&pos]) {
      [enckey addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%o", pos]];
    }
    else {
      NSLog(@"Your DES key appears to be invalid.");
      return;
    }
  }
```

Basically trying to convert ascii DES key to string to use for Triple DES encryption. Any help is greatly appreciated, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Keenan "I was hoping to avoid using sscanf and char* in place of the Cocoa classes". Well you can do that, but what are you hoping to produce? If you want a *byte array* as the result then you need to stick to `unsigned char[]`, and that begs the question why you'd do the parsing on `NSString` in the first place.

Here is an Objective-C translation of your C code. Note that octal is seen as ancient history by Cocoa so its parsing classes only deal with decimal and hexadecimal, so you need to write your own or use a standard C function (`strtol` below).

This example produces both a `unsigned char[]` and an `NSMutableArray` - pick one.

```
// There are no checks in the code, like in the original...
// BTW 789 is not an octal number...
NSString *descKey = @"123 456 789 101 112 131 415 161";         //    char *deskey = "123 456 789 101 112 131 415 161";
// pick one...
NSMutableArray *keyObjC = [NSMutableArray new];                 //    unsigned char key[16];
unsigned char keyC[16];
//    memset(key, 0, sizeof(key));

// As @JeremyP has pointed out the sscanf is wrong as %o produces a 4-byte value and you only want a 1-byte one.
// In C you would therefore need key to be an array of ints and then assign each element to a byte (unsigned char),
// or parse a different way.

unsigned ix = 0;    // for keyC choice only
NSArray *numbers = [descKey componentsSeparatedByString:@" "];  //    sscanf(deskey, "%o %o %o %o %o %o %o %o",
for (NSString *aNumber in numbers)                              //           (int*)&key[0], (int*)&key[1], (int*)&key[2],
{                                                               //           (int*)&key[3], (int*)&key[4], (int*)&key[5],
                                                                //           (int*)&key[6], (int*)&key[7]);
    unsigned char next = (unsigned char)strtol([aNumber UTF8String], NULL, 8);
    keyC[ix++] = next;                                          // for keyC choice
    [keyObjC addObject:[NSNumber numberWithUnsignedChar:next]]; // keyObjC choice
}
```

If you want to approach the one line of your Python just compress the iteration to:

```
for (NSString *aNumber in [descKey componentsSeparatedByString:@" "]) { [keyObjC addObject:[NSNumber numberWithUnsignedChar:(unsigned char)strtol([aNumber UTF8String], NULL, 8)]]; }
```

but it is still longer of course!

Comment: thank you so much for the explaination and answer! I really appreciate your help. :)

Answer (score 0):

The quick and dirty method is to take your original code

```
char *deskey = "123 456 789 101 112 131 415 161";
unsigned char key[16];
memset(key, 0, sizeof(key));
sscanf(deskey, "%o %o %o %o %o %o %o %o",
       (int*)&key[0], (int*)&key[1], (int*)&key[2],
       (int*)&key[3], (int*)&key[4], (int*)&key[5],
       (int*)&key[6], (int*)&key[7]);
```

And add the following line:

```
NSData* keyData = [NSData dataWithBytes: key length: sizeof key];
```

Except that your sscanf looks very wrong.  Elements of key are chars, not ints.

Comment: thank you for your response!  I was hoping to avoid using sscanf and char* in place of the Cocoa classes.  Regarding key, it's how the OpenSSL function EVP_EncryptInit wants it:

`EVP_EncryptInit(&ctx, EVP_des_ecb(), key, NULL);`

I should've been more clear about that in my original post.

Comment: @Keenan: My comment about the wrong looking sscanf is really to do with your casting of the addresses of the elements to int* and the `%o` format.  On a machine with a 32 bit int, each of those pointers is expected to point to a 4 byte location meaning that scanning a value into `(int*)&key[0]` will overwrite `key[0]`, `key[1]`, `key[2]` and `key[3]` with the actual Octal number in either key[0] or key[3] depending on if the architecture is little or big endian.

Comment: Hm, I thought %o expected type int* (or unsigned int*). Here's how I accomplished this in python (which also works with 3DES ecb): `for i in deskey.split(' '): keyData += pack('B', int(i, 8))`. Thanks for the help.

Comment: @Keenan: It does, which is why you can't use `%o` to scan into storage sized for an `unsigned char`.

Answer (score 0):

As CRD has already done a good job of showing you a correct solution, I'll use my answer to explain why your solutions didn't work.

> ```
>   unsigned char key[16];
>   memset(key, 0, sizeof(key));
>   sscanf(deskey, "%o %o %o %o %o %o %o %o",
>     (int*)&key[0], (int*)&key[1], (int*)&key[2],
>     (int*)&key[3], (int*)&key[4], (int*)&key[5],
>     (int*)&key[6], (int*)&key[7]);
> ```

Lying to the compiler never solves problems.

`key` is an array of `unsigned char`s. Telling the compiler, in your function call to `sscanf`, that your pointers into the array are pointers to `int`s does not make them so; the storage each one points to is still storage for an `unsigned char`, and no more.

The result of this is that each attempt to store one `int` at an address you provided overwrites three-quarters of the previous `int`. The result of *that* is that the `sscanf` amounts to little more than a harder way of doing the same thing as the `memset`.

I say “little more” and not “no more” for a reason: The `sscanf` call also writes `sizeof(int) - sizeof(unsigned char)` bytes beyond the end of the array, so you are also smashing the stack and setting up for a potential crash.

> ```
>     if ([scanner scanInt:&pos]) {
>       [enckey addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%o", pos]];
> ```

`scanInt:` parses the number from the string in decimal. `stringWithFormat:` likewise does what its name says: It creates a string. With the format you gave it, it converts a number to a string, not the other way around.

Thus, you use `scanInt:` to parse the number in decimal, and `stringWithFormat:` to convert it to octal (and encode it back into a string). Assuming, from the `sscanf`-based code, that the input was in octal, this is the opposite of what you want.

This code will certainly give you numbers, but it will give you wrong numbers, which is almost as bad as the `sscanf` code that gave you all zeroes plus a crash.

You cannot use NSScanner to scan octal numbers.

I'm also not sure why you called this variable `pos`, as it does not appear to be a position. Certainly that's not what `scanInt:` gives you.

> I was able to scan the string and pull out the numbers, but I'm not sure how to store into NSData after that.

See [the NSData documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSData_Class/).

> I've tried using NSMutableArray and NSData but having no luck.

That has nothing to do with the problem, which is parsing the input data.

I'm not sure whether an NSArray or a C array (the latter optionally wrapped in an NSData) would be the correct place to put the result. It depends on where you want to pass the numbers once you have them parsed.

Comment: Thank you! To close the loop on this, a class I was using required NSData and as you pointed out, I was doing everything wrong to turn my data into NSData. Thank you for your explanation of the problem, I appreciate your help!